# Mean average with range of values as a value in frequency table

Tags: statistics, means

Preface: This is for a homework for a Psychological Statistics class, the other questions are equally badly written or worse. I'm just trying to understand if there's something I'm missing. No good way around this from the lectures that I attend, the book, or the slides from class.

I've emailed my professor, but he has yet to get back to me.
I don't understand how this question is possible to answer because the part where it says "11 or fewer" doesn't seem right to me. Is there something I missed?

I have a basic statistics problem set and one of the questions is as follows:

> X__________f
>
> 15_________20
>
> 14_________20
>
> 13_________10
>
> 12_________50
>
> 11 or fewer___40
>
> What is the mean of the values?

I know that the mean of some set of values (unweighted) is the sum of the values divided by the number of the values summed. This just confounds me. Should I just wait for the professor's response?

Comment: The question should really ask you to estimate the mean, because that is the best you can do. In the category 11 or fewer you have 40 values and no idea how they are distributed. The best you can do is assume an average value of 5.5. So now you have X values 15, 14, 13, 12 and 5.5 and away you go.

Comment: Forgot to update this. The answer was really frustrating and makes me think that the professor is just obnoxious. Anyways, the answer was that this was unanswerable.